# Typescript type signature function array of objects parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the syntax to define onChange in this interface:

```
interface myInterface{
   data: Type1
   onChange : ({field: string, value: any}[]) => void
}
```

It gives me compile error on '=>' (; expected)
I want to say onChange receives an array of field-value pair and return type is void. What is the syntax?

Comment: First you need a *name* for the parameter: `(arr: {...}[])`. Then either pick arrow prop *or* method syntax, not both (`onChange(...): void` **or** `onChange: (...) => void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forgot about `:`

```
interface myInterface{
  data: Type1
  onChange: (arr: {field: string, value: any}[]) => void
}
```